# Tf-idf of strings from csv file

Tags: r, csv, machine-learning, information-retrieval, tf-idf

My `test.csv` file is (without header):

```
very good, very bad, you are great
very bad, good restaurent, nice place to visit
```

I want to make my corpus separated with `,` so that my final `DocumentTermMatrix` becomes:

```
      terms
 docs       very good      very bad        you are great   good restaurent   nice place to visit
  doc1       tf-idf          tf-idf         tf-idf          0                    0
  doc2       0                tf-idf         0                tf-idf             tf-idf
```

I am able to produce the above `DTM` correctly, if I don't load the `documents` from `csv file`, like below:

```
library(tm)
docs <- c(D1 = "very good, very bad, you are great", 
    D2 = "very bad, good restaurent, nice place to visit")

dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))
dd <- tm_map(dd, function(x) {
    PlainTextDocument(
       gsub("\\s+","~",strsplit(x,",\\s*")[[1]]), 
       id=ID(x)
     )
})
inspect(dd)

# A corpus with 2 text documents
# 
# The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
# Available tags are:
#   create_date creator 
# Available variables in the data frame are:
#   MetaID 

# $D1
# very~good
# very~bad
# you~are~great
# 
# $D2
# very~bad
# good~restaurent
# nice~place~to~visit

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
as.matrix(dtm)
```

This will produce

```
# Docs good~restaurent nice~place~to~visit very~bad very~good you~are~great
#   D1       0.0000000           0.0000000        0 0.3333333     0.3333333
#   D2       0.3333333           0.3333333        0 0.0000000     0.0000000
```

If, I am loading the `document` from `csv` file, then only the first term of each document is getting joined like below:

```
> file_loc <- "testdata.csv"
> require(tm)
  Loading required package: tm
> x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = FALSE)
> x <- data.frame(lapply(x, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> dd <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
> dd <- tm_map(dd, stripWhitespace)
> dd <- tm_map(dd, tolower)
>  dd <- tm_map(dd, function(x) {
            PlainTextDocument(
            gsub("\\s+","~",strsplit(x,",\\s*")[[1]]), 
            id=ID(x)
            )
          })
> inspect(dd)
```

Joins only the first terms like this:

```
# $D1
# very~good

# 
# $D2
# very~bad
```

How can I join all the terms and create a `DocumentTermMatrix` like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read data incorrectly. I use `scan` for reading. The following works:

```
docs <- scan("testdata.csv", "character", sep = "\n")

dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
dd <- tm_map(dd, function(x) {
  PlainTextDocument(
    gsub("\\s+","~",strsplit(x,",\\s*")[[1]]), 
    id=ID(x)
  )
})
inspect(dd)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
as.matrix(dtm)
```